# An easy to initialize maintain and use class arrays of const char*?

Tags: c++

I have an external API function that accepts (`const char* const*`) as an argument. I need to come up with an easy way to create such arrays in my class (there are many arrays and function calls), initialise these array some time after a class instance is initialized. I'm also looking for a clean one line syntax for initializing these arrays.

I would be happy with the code below, except the static variable is not visible outside the function:

```
class myClass
{
public:
    template<typename... Ts> void SetVar_RequiredExtensions(Ts... args) {
        const int size = sizeof...(args);
        static char RequiredExtensions[size][MAX_SIZE] = {args...};
    }
    template<typename... Ts> void SetVar_RequiredDevicenames(Ts... args) {
        const int size = sizeof...(args);
        static char RequiredDevicenames[size][MAX_SIZE] = {args...};
    }
}

// usage

myClass mc;
...
mc.SetVar_RequiredExtensions( "Extension one", "Extension two", ... );
mc.SetVar_RequiredDevicenames( "Name one", "Name two", ... );
...

// const char* const*

externalAPIfunctionCall(mc.RequiredExtensions); 
externalAPIfunctionCall(mc.RequiredDevicenames);
...
```

Basically, I'm looking for something like:

```
mc.whateverThatReflectsVariableName "Extension one", "Extension two", ... ;
externalAPIfunctionCall(mc.whateverThatReflectsVariableName);
```

I don't want to use strings and then convert them into `char*` on the fly.

Comment: *I don't want to use strings and then convert them into char\* on the fly* Why?

Comment: you **are** using strings, why do you want it the hard way, when you could use `std::string`?

Comment: btw what is a `const char* char*` ? Do you mean `const char*` ?

Comment: I'm looking for a simpler/cleaner/faster solution that doesn't require multiple conversions. If it exists.

Comment: @user463035818 edited

Comment: Whats wrong with a `std::vector<char const*>`?